# How do I use a view with a child controller in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

In my app I have a Main controller, within the template/view for that controller I call a second controller thru `<div ng-controller="BasketCtrl"></div>`. **But how do I tell 'BasketCtrl' to use a certain view/template?**

I don't want to use this "basket" within my '$routeProvider' since it will be used accross my site.

The basket will be a section of each template that shows the contents of a shoppingcart. Therefor I don't want to create the neccessary HTML within the DIV, that will lead to duplication of a lot of code...am I getting something wrong here perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a basket directive. Something like this:

```
app.directive('basket', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'basket-template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
        }
    }
});
```

You could then include it in as many templates as you'd like. Read more about directives here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Making a directive would be a great idea, depending on whether you are going to reuse it or not. If you aren't going to reuse it, might not make sense.

Comment: @aaronfrost He is reusing it. "The basket will be a section of each template that shows the contents of a shoppingcart"

Comment: @moderndegree you are right. Sorry I didn't read the whole question. A directive would be best. I agree with you.

Comment: No problem. Both solutions would work and I think it is good that we have options.

Answer (score 1):

Just template the BasketController inside of the div that you added the ng-controller to. It is a nested template.

```
<div ng-controller="BasketCtrl">
    <!-- put template inside of basketctrl -->
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you want your basketctrl inside of another file, you could do an ng-include inside of your BasketCtrl and include a link to that template:

```
<div ng-controller="BasketCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'foo/bar/BasketTemplate.html'">
</div>
```

make sure to use both the double quotes and single quotes in there. Otherwise it won't work.